# OSB as primary floor: how to fix it and how to treat it

Tags: flooring, tile, osb

I am considering OSB3 as the primary flooring material for my project. Currently, the floor consists of ceramic tiles, so I'm contemplating the best approach for laying the OSB sheets. The sheets measure 205 cm x 67 cm and are 12 mm thick.

One option to secure the OSB sheets to the existing floor that I am considering is by using Torx screws. I am not concerned about the aesthetics as the Torx screws have a minimal appearance that aligns with my desired style.

Another option that I would consider is using underlay, similar to what is used for laying laminate flooring.

So rather than aesthetics, I am mainly concerned about something that might be cheap, easy to execute and that is durable.

Lastly, I plan to apply varnish to protect the OSB. Should I take any additional measures to protect the small junction gaps between the sheets?

Comment: You're planning on laying OSB directly over tile? You're going to have one heck of a hard time with that. You'll have to drill the OSB for each screw, then use a ceramic bit to drill through the tile, then drive the screw. That will probably take almost as long as it would to pull up the tile in the first place! BTW - what is _under_ the tile? If it's a cement backer board you may have to drill pilot holes for that. If it's poured cement, you'll have to use the proper anchors to get through the cement. TBH, I think this plan needs a serious rethink...

Comment: Are you going to remove the tiles first?  Tiles do not like screws.  Since it is usually recommended to have plus inch wood above joists for tiles, I would prefer to see what I have to work with first.

Comment: @FreeMan  Is there an adhesive that would work to lay OSB on tile?

Comment: Some chipboard or other wood is sheeting underneath. I've still got to double-check to be 100% sure what kind of wood sheeting it is.

Comment: @FreeMan Given the potential difficulty of screwing through the tiles, the question that comes up is: how crucial is it to secure the OSB to the existing floor? I'm curious if it's possible to have a floating OSB floor, like how a laminate floating floor is installed.

Comment: Martin,  This is a bad idea.  It's a bad idea for many reasons, some listed above, but there are others.  If you would go through with it you will regret it in the near future.   Ask yourself why haven't I seen  OSB as a finished floor.

Comment: Honestly, this sounds like an XY Problem. _Why_ do you want to use OSB as a finished floor surface? It's exceedingly unusual and there are multitude of reasons for that. What's your motivating reason for doing this?

Comment: You probably have enough support to have it floating, if the floor is nice and flat(the small grout lines do not matter).  For a finish you might want a marine varnish or epoxy, something nice and heavy duty.

Comment: +1 to "you need to figure out how to attach this before you get much further" and +1 to "varnish the heck out of it, then varnish it some more" to avoid strands of wood coming loose and causing you agony.

Comment: *"cheap, easy to execute and that is durable."* Leave the ceramic tiles alone. Cost=$0.00, €0.00, time taken = none, durability = high.

Comment: @crip659 _IF_ I were to attempt this, I'd think to use something like Liquid Nails™, but I'd read the instructions carefully. After all, I guess you could use it to attach tile to OSB, but you're gluing down the porous _back_ of the tile to the OSB, not the glazed _front_ of the tile. Who knows. There's probably a reason adhesive mfgrs don't list "attach OSB to glazed tile" in their lists of potential applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question as posted:

To affix OSB, you just need wood screws. Torx is not a type of screw, it's a type of screw head, as in flat, phillips, etc. Now, since you are planning on installing this on top of tile, you will need to drill pilot holes, and this will take a lot of time and possibly quite a few drill bits. This is assuming that below the tile you have a cement board and then wood. If you have concrete under the tile, as is common in Europe, then you'll have to use cement screws, e.g. Tapcon. You could also use subfloor adhesive, but this will still require drilling the pilot holes and fasteners. The subfloor adhesive also does not come cheap. You also mention wanting to apply varnish. For this to be effective, you will need a varnish that is made of some type of synthetic thick resin or two-part epoxy. These also don't come cheap, and might end up costing more than the OSB itself.

Now, I don't know why you would want to cover tile with OSB, but I'll assume that you are doing so because the tile is broken and beyond repair, and you are on a short budget. Otherwise, you should not use OSB. OSB will be hard to clean (it will destroy your mop), destroy your socks as you walk on it, stain quickly, and will look ugly to most people. If you do a quick math, by the time you are done with buying the OSB, drill bits, subfloor adhesive, screws, and epoxy/resin, you will have spent more money than just laying down some cheap tile or vinyl.

But let's say that you are dead-set on using sheet wood as flooring. Go with plywood at least. For many years I lived on a house with plywood floors. It was not a design choice, but there was no money for flooring, and we had to walk on something. You can sand plywood and it can be cleaned.

Answer (score 2):

OSB is not a flooring material at all.

Choose something more suitable, like roofing shingles lol (no, don't use shingles).

Come to think of it, EPDM rubber roof would be a more workable choice a "what were you thinking?" tier choice for a flooring material.  Also, it's glued down, which will solve the huge problem you're just ignoring about how to convince screws to go through tile.